# Pre-trained model offered by TensorFlow with COCO (inception v3 and v4)

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

On this link https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md we have some pre trained models that reference inception v2 and v1.

If models v3 and v4 are better, why we don't have this models pre-trained with COCO?

Answer (score 0):

Because it takes a long time to train a model on an expensive computer. Not all models are going to be available all the time. You are welcome to train it yourself and upload the weights.